# Excel Add-In for Microsoft Office (AMO) - Deleting Stored Process Object and Retaining Values using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sas

**Software Versions**

**SAS** : 9.4M4
**SAS Add-in for Microsoft Office** : 8.0
**Excel** : 2016

Good Afternoon,

I have two stored processes:

The first takes input entered into various cells within the Excel spreadsheet, queries a Dataset and returns the values to 64 non-contiguous cells.

The second takes the values from the 64 non-contiguous cells (some values in these cells will be changed by the end-user, hence why there needs to be a second stored process) and calls a series of code elements to transform the data so that it can be loaded into another table.

Sounds pretty simple, however I am unable to pass the values from the 64 cells as prompts to the second stored process because the data is stored in the first stored process object and therefore can't be used as prompt values.  To counter this issue I decided to record a macro by selecting the "Close Select Items" from the home tab in the automatically surfaced SAS Panel (as per the attached screenshot).

[image]

This does precisely what I want it to do and disconnects from stored process object whilst retaining the values (something that the delete method fails to do).  The VBA generated by this process is:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.0").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.1").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.2").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.3").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.4").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.5").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.6").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.7").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.8").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.9").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.10").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.11").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.12").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.13").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.14").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.15").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.16").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.17").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.18").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.19").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.20").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.21").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.22").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.23").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.24").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.25").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.26").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.27").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.28").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.29").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.30").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.31").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.32").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916.33").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentDefinition_194379916").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
 "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_AFFINITY_BRAND").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
 "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_AFFINITY_ENTITY").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_AFFINITY_GROUP").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_AGE" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_GENDER").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_NO_DRIVERS_ALLOWED").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_AGE" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_CLMS_CNT_NW_1YR").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_CLMS_CNT_NW_5YR").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_GENDER").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_IS_YOUNGEST_DRIVER"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_NCD" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_OCCUPATION_STATUS"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_AGE" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_GENDER").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_AGE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_BREAKDOWN").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_CHOICE_OF_REPAIRER").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_DRIVER" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_HIRE_CAR").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_NCD_PROTECTION").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_RATE_1_FOR_LIFE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_WINDSCREEN").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_PRODUCT"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_RAD_METHOD_OF_PARKING").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_RAD_POSTCODE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_ACCESS_VALUE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_AGE"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_AGREED_MARKET_VALUE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_ALARM_FITTED").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_BODY_ENGINE_MOD").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_BODY_STYLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_BULL_BAR_FITTED").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_COLOUR" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_DRIVE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_ENGINE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_FACTORY_OPTIONS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_FINANCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_INSURED_VALUE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_KMS"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_MAKE"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_MODEL") _
    .Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_PREVIOUS_INS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_ContentLocation_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_USE_CODE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_AFFINITY_BRAND").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_AFFINITY_ENTITY").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_AFFINITY_GROUP").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_AGE"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_GENDER" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_BD_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_NO_DRIVERS_ALLOWED").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_AGE"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_CLMS_CNT_NW_1YR").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_CLMS_CNT_NW_5YR").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_GENDER" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_IS_YOUNGEST_DRIVER").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_NCD"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_OCCUPATION_STATUS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_RD_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_AGE"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_GENDER" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YD_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_AGE") _
    .Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_LICENCE_HELD_MTHS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_LICENCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_DD_YDNL_OTHER_VEHICLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_BREAKDOWN" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_CHOICE_OF_REPAIRER").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_DRIVER"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_HIRE_CAR") _
    .Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_NCD_PROTECTION").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_RATE_1_FOR_LIFE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PO_WINDSCREEN").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_PRODUCT"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_RAD_METHOD_OF_PARKING").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_RAD_POSTCODE" _
    ).Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_ACCESS_VALUE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_AGE"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_AGREED_MARKET_VALUE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_ALARM_FITTED").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_BODY_ENGINE_MOD").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_BODY_STYLE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_BULL_BAR_FITTED").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_COLOUR"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_DRIVE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_ENGINE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_FACTORY_OPTIONS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_FINANCE_TYPE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_INSURED_VALUE").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_KMS"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_MAKE"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_MODEL"). _
    Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names( _
    "_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_PREVIOUS_INS").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names("_AMO_SingleObject_194379916_OutputParameter_VD_USE_CODE") _
    .Delete
End Sub
```

The problem is that every time a new stored process object is created a new object number is allocated (which makes complete sense).  The question is, is this stored somewhere that I can obtain it, and build it into my VBA so regardless of the identifier for the object I will be able to disconnect the Stored Process object?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Scott,

Can I reframe the question which is what is the business purpose of what you are trying to do. I mention that because you are using a flawed process to start and then you are dealing with the aftermath of that flawed start.

An Excel file, xlsx, is an XML file zipped up. In many modern applications, Excel is not even required on a system to generate and read Excel. Rather than using VBA, consider switching to a system that reads and writes Excel vs the SAS Excel Add-In. Then use SAS after you accomplish your goal.

Consider this: use .NET Core along with EPPlus. Download Visual Studio Community edition, add Nuget package for EPPlus, read and write the Excel file and forget VBA. Use C# as the language base. Then apply the SAS Add-In where it is needed. I think it will cost a bit of learning early on and save you tremendous amounts of headache long-term. VBA works but is pretty deprecated.

This is from a former SAS consultant who specializes in SAS/Excel. How much faster is this process vs what you are doing? 1000x, maybe.

The moderators may get upset about the lack of direct answer but you are asking about bailing out a dingy you took on an ocean voyage. Start with a better boat and ignore the bailing problem.

Comment: BTW, you can call a SAS stored process outside of Excel and generate Excel worksheets from it without ever opening Excel.